# python socket not connecting to web server

Tags: python, sockets, socketserver

I'm trying use the python `socket` module to connect to an ngrok server. If I put the ngrok into my browser it connects properly so the problem is somewhere with my client code. Here is the server code:

```
#server.py
import socketserver
class MyTCPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        print("{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0]))
        print(self.data)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "192.168.86.43", 8080
    server = socketserver.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
```

And here is the client:

```
#client.py
import socket
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
    sock.connect(("http://urlhere.ngrok.io", 8080))
    sock.sendall(bytes("Hello" + "\n", "utf-8"))
```

Thanks!

Comment: The address that you're connecting to is not correct. Try using `192.168.86.43`

Comment: @RobertNavado I want to be able to connect even if I'm not on my network so I can't use the internal IP

Answer (score 0):

In general you should be able to connect to any globally available address or DNS name, ensuring there is no network restrictions on the way. However you have to listen on the address that is locally available for global routing if you are communicating across the Internet.

As for particular code, there are 2 issues:

1. Socket should be connected to an address or DNS name. The protocol is defined with the socket type. In your case

```
import socket
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
    sock.connect(("localhost", 8080))
    sock.sendall(bytes("Hello" + "\n", "utf-8"))
```

2. You're binding in the server to some speciffic not related address. To run your code you should bind to either localhost or to "any available" address "0.0.0.0":

```
import socketserver
class MyTCPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        print("{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0]))
        print(self.data)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "0.0.0.0", 8080
    server = socketserver.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: I want to be able to connect even if I'm not on the same network, is this possible with your method?

Comment: Also the IP is not the issue, if I run connect to 192.168.86.43 it works but I want to be able to connect to the ngrok that forwards to 192.168.86.43

Comment: @TanujKS: You can specify the DNS name in the `connect()` call, you just can't use the URL form. Thus  `sock.connect(("urlhere.ngrok.io", 8080))` should connect.

Comment: Yes. You can connect to any globally available address or DNS name, ensuring there is no network restrictions on the way. However you have to listen on the address that is locally available for global routing if your're communicating across the Internet.